# How to register indexed property in RemObject?

Tags: delphi, pascalscript, remobjects

I want to register property Strings of TStrings class. When I register a simple property, I write:

```
ACompiler.FindClass(ClassName).RegisterProperty(PropertyName,PropertyTypeName, PSPropType);
```

in OnCompImport Event

and

```
ARuntimeImporter.FindClass(ClassName).RegisterPropertyHelper(GetterCodeAddress, SetterCodeAddress, PropertyName);
```

in OnExecImport Event. 
But I have not found any RegisterIndexedProperty and RegisterIndexedPropertyHelper methods.

Comment: I know nothing about RemObjects, but wouldn't `RegisterProperty()` handle any kind of property, whether it is indexed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need write: property type, index type 1, index type 2, etc in property type parametrs. For Example:

```
    ACompiler.FindClass('TStringList').RegisterProperty('Strings',' String Integer',iptRW);
```

And in implementation method Value of a property type must be at the first place. For Example:

```
procedure GetStringsMethod(Self: TObject; var AValue: string; AIndex: Integer);

procedure SetStringsMethod(Self: TObject; const AValue: string; AIndex: Integer);
```